# Creating a Network Member Record in a Screen Flow

Tags: user, screen-flow, experience

We have an experience site available to the public. Anyone can submit a User Access Request  (UAR) to gain access to the site and perform some tasks. The requests have to be vetted internally first, but we do expect a medium-high volume of requests so we want to automate processing these requests if they are approved internally.

In order to do that, I created a screen flow that allows an internal user to create the Contact for the new person and the associated User record based on the details from the UAR. I have this process mostly working now but the piece I am missing is how to make the user be a member of the experience within the flow. I see there is a junction object called [NetworkMember](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_networkmember.htm), which I figured is what I need. However, I am not provided the option to create a NetworkMember record in the flow so I'm not sure how would create a user's membership to an experience.

I have a Create Records element in the flow, but when selecting "Use separate resources, and literal values" the object NetworkMember doesn't even show up. When selecting "Use all values from a record" the single record variable I created isn't available for selection in the "Record" box (see screenshots). I do have the permission to Create and Set Up Experiences discussed in the documentation.

So with all that being said, the question is:
***How can I create a user's membership to an experience within the flow?***

For this use case, Apex is out of the question. If it cannot be done declaratively, I will automate as much as possible and have the internal user go through the "Enable Customer User" button for the rest of it.

[image: trying to create the record from a record variable]

[image: NetworkMember single record variable]

Comment: [Access to the site](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_customize_members.htm&language=en_US&type=5) is based on profile or perm set (Site -> Membership). `NetworkMember` is an outcome of this, you shouldn't have to create it.

Comment: giving the user a ProfileId or PermissionSetAssignment that is provisioned to the Experience is all that is required

Comment: Hmmm, that's odd. I have a few users associated with a contact that I was testing with, and when I try to use the "Log In to Experience as User" button from the Contact record, I get a message saying "Looks like this portal user is not a member of an experience or your experience is down. Ask your Salesforce admin or channel manager for help." which made me think I needed to do something else. The user in question (and others I tried) are all members of the experience by both profile and permission set

Answer (score 0):

For future reference:
As indicated by cropredy and identigral, there is no need to create a Network Member record. Instead granting the user access via permission set or profile is all that is needed.

The error I was getting when clicking the Log In to Experience As User button ("Looks like this portal user is not a member of an experience or your experience is down. Ask your Salesforce admin or channel manager for help.") was because my experience had been temporarily deactivated. Once activated, it worked just fine. Thank you both!